# Azure local environment: "500 - Internal server error." after migration to different machine

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

Please help - I have being trying to solve this problem for days.

I am running a very simple Web Role application containing RESTful WCF in local environment. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Azure version 2.2 . In one of my machines (Windows 7, 32 bits) the application works as expected. But when being built and run in another machine (Windows 7, 64 bits) it causes the following error:

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

If you will kindly decide to help then you can download the application from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rm361nyqq51eoxz/SimpleSample.zip?n=2855111).

This is just few lines of code.

Request

http: //127.0.0.1:81/ImagingSvc.svc/Init

causes the above error, whereas expected response on this request is word TEST surrounded with some HTML stuff.

When app. starts method WebRole.OnStart() works fine (I debugged it), but after browser request breakpoint in ImagingSvc.Init() method was never hit.

Thank you in advance.

Igor

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: As I have written in my first post, I tried debugging. Breakpoint in WebRole.OnStart() was hit, but breakpoint in WCF service method and even static ctor there (I removed it later) were never hit.

Comment: First of all, there's no reference here to any "first post" so that assumes that people here will figure out that they need to go digging through your question history to find more details. Additionally, you're asking people to debug your code for you by downloading, compiling, and executing it. Neither of these two actions is something you should expect. Instead, *you* need to do all this, and post all the information that is necessary here so that others here *don't* have to do those things. Otherwise, your question will not get much attention at all.

Comment: To begin with, "500 internal server error" is a dummy error message usually given by Internet Explorer. Can you find the *real* error message that your server produces and show that instead?

Comment: To Lesse V. Karlsen: I’ll clarify something to you. I don’t expect but rather hope on kind help from fellow developers. But I do expect respectful attitude to me. Style of your letter is more suitable for communication with your pet rather than with your colleague. You didn’t even read my question to the end (where I referred to my debugging). As for possible download: I provided maximum information I had AND in addition my code stripped from anything not related to the question. You answer is rather banal and of no use at all. You didn’t explain how to gather additional information.

Comment: To Lesse V. Karlsen: Your statement that this message came from Internet Explorer is wrong: the message has nothing to do with particular browser.

Comment: That might not be entirely true. Internet Explorer has a threshold, where an error message below it will trigger a replacement error message locally. Try going into the options, find the "Helpful error messages" and turn that off, then try again, see if anything changes. That is, *if* you're using IE. You may not be, and obviously your server may actually return a page that says just 500 server error, but then you really should dig around to find out what the actual error message is. Perhaps it's logged?

Comment: Also note that when I tried your code, despite saying it's unlikely anyone will want to do that, it returned TEST, specifically: `<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">TEST</string>`